# Lock Ordering in C3p0

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am trying to log the creation and destruction of database connections in our application using c3p0's `ConnectionCustomizer`. In it, I have some code that looks like this:

```
log(C3P0Registry.getPooledDataSources())
```

I'm running into deadlocks. I'm discovering that c3p0 has at least a couple of objects in its library that use synchronized methods, and don't seem to specify their intended lock ordering. When I log the connections, I'm holding a lock on `C3P0Registry` and eventually `PoolBackedDataSource` (simply creating a list of the datasources is accessing the hashcode causing a lock).

Shutting down the connection provider (calling `C3P0ConnectionProvider.close()`) causes the locks to be called in the opposite order. But while the child datasources are being shut down, my logging is being triggered. The result is a deadlock.

It seems like both calls I am making into the c3p0 library are valid, expected calls:

- `C3P0ConnectionProvider.close()`
- `C3P0Registry.getPooledDataSources()`

It also seems like (unless explicitly stated in the documentation) it should be the library's responsibility to manage it's own locking strategy. (I don't say this to blame anyone.. just to confirm my understanding of best practices)

How should I deal with this issue? Since c3p0 uses synchronized methods rather than a more modern mechanism, I can't really test the locks.

From my `DataSource` closing code, I could first grab the `C3P0Registry` lock before closing the `DataSource`. I would be guessing at the correct lock order, which I don't know if I feel comfortable with.

I don't think I could reverse the lock order for the logging call. I need the `C3P0Registry` to get the list of `DataSources`, so I couldn't lock the `DataSources` without first locking `C3P0Registry` to get references to them.

Another solution, of course is to provide another, higher level lock above everything c3p0. In the case of a connection pool, that seems to defeat the point.

For now, I'm rolling back my logging. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Experiencing something similar, interested in whether you've found more information on this.

Comment: I ended up adding a synchronized block around the code that calls close() to guarantee I'm obtaining locks in the same order as my logging.  It's sloppy, but then again, so is the locking strategy in C3p0.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to fix the locking issue, but i think you should take a step back here and think about the original problem.
"I am trying to log the creation and destruction of database connections in our application ..."

I would recommend the following.

Create a class and make it implement javax.sql.DataSource.
Create a field of the same type and delegate all methods to it.
In the getConnection() method return your own Connection class wrapping around
java.sql.Connection and so on.
Then wrap this class around your original data source.
In your classes you can now simply create a logger and log all actions you want to see in your log.